# adding an existing user to my sales app

Tags: query, deployment, adderror

scenerio:
.......both user A and B are on salesforce......
**user A** runs a little Ad agency,
**user B** requires the help of **User A**, as a mentor.

My Question:
why can't it be possible for **user** B to invite **user A**, give him user right/ role/ permission set to what ever profile level?
where is the collaboration?

I hope this can be walked around? because i must say
that regardless the fact that salesforce has done a good job so far, but in all sense of logic, why can't i invite an entirely different user to my app, should that user be relevant to me business?

Comment: When you say `invite an entirely different user to my app`, what do you mean by this? Salesforce is very much customizable and you can achieve this by customization. Or you can use partner community and invite any contact to self register themselves , it all depends on your use case, for now, from a very high level, the requirement looks like it can be achieved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I was just frustrating after trying for hours to find a way around this obstacles. Here is my situation:

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I was just frustrating after trying for hours to find a way around this obstacles. Here is my situation:                     . scenerio: .......both user A and B are on salesforce...... user A runs a little Ad agency, user B requires the help of User A, as a mentor.

Is it possible for user B to give user A, user right to work freely as an admin would, in his workspace?